# Special text to convert in vertex and nodes to get paths for a Graph

Tags: python, tuples

I have this text and I wish to convert it to a list of tuples like this

```
[(0, 3), (1, 0), (2, 1), (2, 6)....)]
```

Text

```
0 -> 3 \n, 1 -> 0\n 2 -> 1,6\n...
```

Comment: You have a comma before 1, but no comma before 2, is that a typo? What have you tried?

Comment: the text is like 2 -> 1,6 in lines so its not a typo is the text that is given to the task. mean that 2 forms a node with 1 and 6 or like (2, 1), (2, 6)... each line its like a num -> num2 or sometimes num -> num1, num2...

Comment: I meant this comma:  3 \n, 1

Comment: I try to use replace but the code wasn't cool...

Comment: 3\n, means that each num -> num2 is a line. Sorry i didn't got to put the text as it is here...many rules to post

Comment: Yes I know that,  but why is `3 \n,` and not `0\n` (i.e no comma after the second line)

Comment: 3 -> 0,4...(3, 0), (3,4)...now i got it its a typo. Sorry

Comment: Also in the tuples you want there is one with a single element `(1, )` I believe it should be (1, 0).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming text is like:

```
text = "0 -> 3 \n 1 -> 0\n 2 -> 1,6\n"
```

You could do something like this:

```
result = []
for line in text.splitlines():
    clean = line.strip()
    source, targets = map(str.strip,  clean.split('->'))

    source = int(source)
    result.extend((source, target) for target in map(int, targets.split(',')))

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[(0, 3), (1, 0), (2, 1), (2, 6)]
```

Note that this is a *toy example* probably you need to read a file line by line.